# Error: cannot execute: Permission denied CLI Node.js

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

Could someone suggest what I do wrong. I am building my first CLI node.js on Windows and when I run command `mycli`  in terminal it gives me that error:
`cannot execute: Permission denied`
I googled and found solition, I run `chmod +x ./bin/index.js` but still have this error.
If I do  `cd bin` and run command `mycli` I can see the executed "Hello World" but if in terminal I check permissions using command  `ls -l index.js` still the same error, when I run `chmod +x index.js`  it returns `bash: chomd: command not found`
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the terminal as, **Run as Administraor**
And execute the code after changing the directory to, **node mycli**

Comment: it says Cannnot find module

Comment: @zulfiya you need to navigate to the folder before executing